# Trying to find a recursive algorithm for the largest weight of a tree

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree

I am trying to find a recursive algorithm that find the largest possible weight of a tree, with the limitation that if a node is in the final solution then none of its children can be in the final solution. However the children of the children can be in the solution

```
 int MT (Node node)
{
    if(node.children.size()==0)
    {
        return node.data;
    }
    else
    {
        int ktotal=0;
        if(node.children.size() != 0)
        {   
            for (int i =0; i<node.children.size();i++ )
            {
                ktotal=MT(node.children.get(i));
            }
        }
        return Math.max(ktotal, node.data);
    }

}
```

this is the code i currently have but it returns the weight of the root node. I would greatly apprectiate some help

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, but the for loop always returns the value of the last child to be inspected. So if the weight of the root tends to be larger than the weight of the last child of the last child, then you will always get the root weight.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is wrong. It returns the weight of the last node always. It would be something like this.

```
if (node.children.size() > 0)
    ktotal= MT(node.children.get(0));
for (int i =1; i<node.children.size();i++ )
{
    ktotal=Math.max(ktotal,MT(node.children.get(i)));
}
```